# List of all options the `Import` command takes for `JPEG` files?

Tags: import, image, options

If I do

```
Options[Plot]
```

I properly get a list of options the `Plot` command can take. Now, if I try the same with

```
Options[Import]
```

the list is empty. In particular, I am interested in options that can be provided for importing `JPEG` files. But if I try

```
Options[Import[#,"JPEG"]&]
```

I get an error message instead of a result. I am certain that there are some options one can supplement to the `Import[#,"JPEG"]&` routine. How can I get a full list of options this routine can take?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Import` options cannot be retrieved like this with with `Options`.  The options are different for each format, and they are documented separately on every format page, e.g. [JPEG](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/JPEG.html).

Sometimes not all of the import options or elements are documented.  In this case you can take a look at the appropriate file in this directory:

```
SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Formats"}]
```

This does not reveal undocumented options for JPEG, but it does reveal some new import elements, such as `"ImageNoExif"`.

To learn more about what the files in this directory are, read here, and also follow the Related Tutorials links:

- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingAnImportConverter.html

Generally, available import elements (not options) can also be listed using

```
Import["file.jpeg", "Elements"]
```